# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to login through Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have tried my best to write a login script in Selenium for the following site https://www.topmba.com/app. Here is my code:

```
public class TopMba {
    String driverPath = "/usr/bin/chromedriver";
    WebDriver driver;
    String username = "test@gmail.com"; // Change to your username and passwrod
    String password = "12345";
    // This method is to navigate topmba URL
    @BeforeClass
    public void init() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath); 
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.topmba.com");
    }
    // To log in topmba
    @Test
    public void login() {
        driver.findElement(By.className("tm-user")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tm-modal-frame-nvtfa7vvbm\"]")));
        driver.findElement(By.id("edit-user")).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.id("edit-pass")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.id("edit-submit")).click();
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();}
    @AfterClass
    public void quit() {
        driver.close();
    }
```

Here is the Exception :

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="tm-modal-frame-nvtfa7vvbm"]"}

Comment: this is not a "gimme codezz" group. Selenium is a testing tool, not a login tool, btw

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because he's requesting us to do his work

Comment: Please show any code you have tried so far.

Comment: I have tried my best to write a login script , show us first ?

Comment: You can inspect element and check.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
    driver.get("https://www.topmba.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    String parentWindowHandle =  driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.findElement(By.className("tm-user")).click();
    WebElement  iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'app/sso/user/login')]"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-name")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-pass")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-submit")).click();
    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandle);
```

Comment: See why ['Try This: {code}' Answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality) are not helpful to other readers and are prone to downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to take care as follows :

- To click on the *icon* with *tooltip* as **Login** you have used :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.className("tm-user")).click();
  ```

  If you look at the HTML this *Locator Strategy* identifies the element uniquely but for a more focused click you need to target the `<span>` tag which is within an `<a>` tag which is within the `<li>` tag with the `class` attribute you have used. Of-coarse you have induce *WebDriverWait*.
- Once the **Sign In** *Dialog Box* opens up you will observe the login fields are within an `<iframe>`. So you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for both the cases, once for the *frame to be available* and for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution :
- Code Block :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.topmba.com");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("li.tm-user>a.tmba-user>span.fa-img-icons.fa-img-user"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='/app/sso/user/login']")));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.input-block-level.form-text.required.form-control#edit-name"))).sendKeys("khawar");
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.input-block-level.form-text.required.form-control#edit-pass")).sendKeys("khawar");
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-warning.btn-block.button.js-form-submit.form-submit#edit-submit")).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot :

[image: khawar]